# SQL query in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is it good if i write query like this:- (see query in where condition)

```
SELECT distinct(id) "idea_id" 
FROM ideas 
WHERE deleted_by_user = 0 AND moderation_flag = 1 AND 
user_id in (select id 
            from users 
            where confirm like "yes") 
ORDER BY time_of_creation DESC
```

let me know if there is some issue in this query :
thanx in advance..

Comment: confirm=yes why use like

Comment: Is "yes" a column or a string?

Comment: "yes" is just a string to show confirmed user. yes @harry i forgot to write = operator instead of like..

Comment: and you need to quote with ' if yes is a string... ;-) (been there done it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wirte this query in two ways:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(i.id) "idea_id" 
FROM ideas i 
INNER JOIN users u ON i.user_id = u.id 
WHERE i.deleted_by_user = 0 AND i.moderation_flag = 1 AND u.confirm = 'yes' 
ORDER BY i.time_of_creation DESC;
```

And

```
SELECT DISTINCT(i.id) "idea_id" 
FROM ideas i 
WHERE i.deleted_by_user = 0 AND i.moderation_flag = 1 AND 
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users u WHERE i.user_id = u.id  AND u.confirm = 'yes')
ORDER BY i.time_of_creation DESC;
```

Comment: what is the difference between your first query and mine query?? both gives same result..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct i.id "idea_id" 
FROM ideas i join users u
on i.user_id=u.id and u.confirm ='yes'
WHERE i.deleted_by_user = 0 
AND i.moderation_flag = 1 
ORDER BY i.time_of_creation DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  distinct a.ID idea_id
FROM    ideas a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.user_id = b.id
WHERE   a.deleted_by_user = 0 AND 
        a.moderation_flag = 1 
        b.confirm = 'YES'
ORDER BY time_of_creation DESC
```

Comment: this time_of_creation column is not there in select list still will it work?

Comment: @AnandPhadke yes, as long as it's found on the tables.

Comment: thanx @AnadPhadke but both queries will give same result . Then what is the difference between both of them??

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - there are no problems with using subqueries.

On the other hand, you have (at least) three different things to think about when writing a query in one way or another:

1. How efficient will the data base run my query? (If the data base is small, this may not matter at all)
2. How easy is this to formulate and write? - which often connects to
3. How easy is this to understand for someone else who reads my code? (and I may myself count as "somebody else" if I look into code I've written a year ago...)

If you have a database of a size where efficiency counts, the best way to select how to formulate a query is normally to write it in different ways and test it on the data base. (but often the query optimizer in the data base is so good, it does not matter)

Comment: hey @MortenSickel thanx. I thought performance may degrade ifwe write queries in where clause. See this query.. select DISTINCT(i.id) idea_id from ideas i,responses r where i.id in (SELECT DISTINCT(r1.idea_id) FROM responses r1 WHERE (r1.status like 'UNDER REVIEW' OR r1.status like 'PLANNED' OR r1.status like 'STARTED') AND r1.time_of_creation = ( SELECT max(time_of_creation) FROM responses WHERE idea_id= r1.idea_id)) AND i.deleted_by_user=0 AND i.spammed_by_user=0  AND i.user_id in (select id from users where confirm like 'yes') ORDER BY i.time_of_creation DESC...Any suggestion please tell